# Disable second screen on the login screen but enable once login has completed

Tags: multiple-monitors, login-screen

I currently run Ubuntu 13.04. I recently got a second screen for my computer and I have noticed because they are different resolutions (one is 4:3, one is 16:10) the login screen is duplicated and stretched. Is there anyway to disable the second screen on boot and then turn it on again after login? I would assume I would have to add a script to init.d, which I tried but it didn't seem to work.

My primary monitor (the one I want to keep on) is 16:10 and is plugged in via DVI and my secondary monitor is 4:3 and is plugged in via Display Port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try http://cornerofattention.com/post/44651232151/ubuntu-12-10-disable-second-monitor-while-on-login . This works fine for me.

Here are steps from link above.

Find the name of the display that you are trying to shut off while the greeter is displayed.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ xrandr | grep connected
```

Create a script to disable the second monitor. I put mine in */etc/lightdm/* but it can go anywhere as long as it has sufficient permissions.

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/monitor1-off.sh
```

The contents of the script will be similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output HDMI1 --off
```

Replace **HDMI1** with your display’s name and save it.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod +x /etc/lightdm/monitor1-off.sh
```

Edit **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** and add the following line to the file

```
greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/monitor1-off.sh
```

Save the file and restart your computer.  When the greeter starts, the display you chose should shut off. On my computer the display starts again on its own as soon as I log in.

Comment: instead of providing link, try to provide the steps to follow, so that it should not be a problem if that link expires

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to askubuntu. I've just edited my answer

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was out of the country. I just tried the steps that you mentioned and while it does disable the second screen on the login screen (it re-enables after login just as you said) but the actual login screen still is stretched despite the lower resolution screen being off.

Comment: This is still useful in 2021 running Ubuntu Budgie! Because Budgie uses a modified version of LightDM, adding greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/secondary-monitor-off.sh to the end of the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50_budgie-desktop.conf works like a charm. Thank you so much!