# How to disable monitor connected to laptop until I am logged in with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, lightdm

I have an issue where my monitor plugged into my laptop displays pixelated, fuzzy, etc when turning my computer on, once I have logged in the monitor display is fine. I have asked everywhere for a fix but nobody can solve it. Therefore I just want to have my plugged in monitor turned off until I have logged in to the desktop.

I can see in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348981/disable-second-screen-on-the-login-screen-but-enable-once-login-has-completed) it is possible with earlier Ubuntu versions but there is no lightdm in 18.04 - how can I do this in 18.04?

Comment: how threre is no lightdm in 18.04?? - i am using it right now

Comment: I have no lightdm files as per the linked answer, maybe it's in a different location?